# POST variables not recognised on server side

Tags: php, variables, post, server-side

I've just moved over from shared to dedicated hosting, and suddenly POST is not working. The variables are being sent according to firebug

```
jquery....min.js (line 4)
HeadersPostResponseHTML
Parametersapplication/x-www-form-urlencoded
current_subtab_1    0
current_tab_1   0
delivery_options    Standard (5 working days)
new_copies  1500
p_binding   Portrait
p_colours_fs    Full Colour. (CMYK Process)
p_colours_fs_c  No Lamination
p_colours_t Full Colour. (CMYK Process)
p_copies    1000
p_cover Self Cover
p_cover_c   Silk
p_format    A4 (Portrait Only)
p_pages 8
p_paper 130 GSM, coated
p_paper_type    Silk
Source
current_tab_1=0&current_subtab_1=0&delivery_options=Standard+(5+working+days)&    p_copies=1000&p_paper=130+GSM%2C+coated&p_paper_type=Silk&p_colours_t=Full+Colour.+(CMYK+Process)&p_pages=8&p_binding=Portrait&p_format=A4+(Portrait+Only)&p_cover=Self+Cover
```

But when I turn on error reporting on the server side, it says all variables are undefined. Yes they are defined correctly and the scripts worked fine before...

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  current_tab_1 in <b>calculate.php</b> on line     <b>6</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  current_tab_1 in <b>calculate.php</b> on line     <b>215</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  current_subtab_1 in <b>calculate.php</b> on line     <b>216</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index:  p_format in <b>calculate.php</b> on line <b>220</b><br />
```

etc

So why is it doing this? Is there something I need to changed (a php.ini, config) setting? It must be a PHP thing

**UPDATE:**

I did a `print_r($_POST);` to see if anything is being posted and it returned an empty array

**EDIT:**

client side

```
if (current_tab == 0) {
    if (current_subtab == 0) {
        if ($("#saddle_brochure_copies").val() != "Please select...") {
            if ($("#saddle_brochure_copies").val().match('^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$')) {

                if ($("#saddle_brochure_copies").val() != 25000) {
                    var new_copies = $('#saddle_brochure_copies option:selected').next().val(); //get next selected option for offer price
                }

                var p_copies = $("#saddle_brochure_copies"),
                    p_paper = $("#saddle_brochure_paper"),
                    p_paper_type = $("#saddle_brochure_paper_type"),
                    p_colours_t = $("#saddle_brochure_colours_t"),
                    p_pages = $("#saddle_brochure_pages"),
                    p_binding = $("#saddle_brochure_binding"),
                    p_format = $("#saddle_brochure_format"),
                    p_cover = $("#saddle_brochure_cover"),
                    p_cover_c = $("#saddle_brochure_cover_c"),
                    p_colours_fs = $("#saddle_brochure_colours_fs"),
                    p_colours_fs_c = $("#saddle_brochure_colours_fs_c"),
                    allFields = $([]).add(p_copies).add(p_paper).add(p_paper_type).add(p_colours_t).add(p_pages).
                                    add(p_binding).add(p_format).add(p_cover).add(p_cover_c).add(p_colours_fs).add(p_colours_fs_c),
                                    tips = $(".validateTips");

                $.post("order/calculate.php", {
                    current_tab_1: current_tab,
                    current_subtab_1: current_subtab,
                    delivery_options: delivery_options.val(),
                    p_copies: p_copies.val(),
                    p_paper: p_paper.val(),
                    p_paper_type: p_paper_type.val(),
                    p_colours_t: p_colours_t.val(),
                    p_pages: p_pages.val(),
                    p_binding: p_binding.val(),
                    p_format: p_format.val(),
                    p_cover: p_cover.val(),
                    p_cover_c: p_cover_c.val(),
                    p_colours_fs: p_colours_fs.val(),
                    p_colours_fs_c: p_colours_fs_c.val(),
                    new_copies: new_copies
                }, function (data) {
                    var resultArray = eval('(' + data + ')');
                    checkIfNull();
                    $(".value_2").append("&pound;");
                    if ($("#hf_quote").val() != null) {
                        $("#hf_quote").val(null);
                    }
                    $("#hf_quote").val(resultArray[0]);
                    if ($("#hf_vat").val() != null) {
                        $("#hf_vat").val(null);
                    }
                    $("#hf_vat").val(resultArray[1]);
                    cashFlow($('.value'), 0, resultArray[0], 1 * 1000, 0);
                    if (resultArray[1] != "No VAT on this product!") {
                        $("#quote_vat").append("&pound;", resultArray[1], " Inc. VAT");
                    } else {
                        $("#quote_vat").append(resultArray[1]);
                    }
                    if (resultArray[2]) {
                        if ($("#quote_offer").text() != null) {
                            $("#quote_offer").text("");
                        }
                        $("#quote_offer").append("Get ", new_copies, " copies for &pound;", resultArray[2]);
                    }
                });
```

print_r($_REQUEST);  returns -

```
Array (
    [ppRemember] => 35iq0m8oi3ldr1f8603sifpv52 [__utma] => 201771013.995365705.1339148067.1339148067.1339155188.2 [__utmc] => 201771013 [__utmz] => 201771013.1339148067.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none) [__utmb] => 201771013.9.10.1339155188
)
```

`print_r($_GET);` returns empty array

**server side code in question**

```
if ($_POST['current_tab_1']==0) {
   if ($_POST['current_subtab_1']==0) {
    //for saddle stitched brochures
    //cost 1

    $format = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_format'],0,100)); //format
    $B = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_copies'],0,10)); //copies
    $C1 = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_paper'],0,100)); //paper inner pages
    $C2 = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_cover'],0,100));
    $lamination = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_colours_fs_c'],0,100)); //lamination
    $P = strip_tags(substr($_POST['p_pages'],0,100));
    $new_copies = strip_tags(substr($_POST['new_copies'],0,100));

    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried echo $_POST['current_tab_1']; right at the top of script and it returned an undefined error.

Also noticed one of the errors is this...?

**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined function json_encode() in **calculate.php** on line **975**

which is a built in function.. right?

Comment: Without any code, we can't help you.

Comment: Might be obvious, but are you sure you're doing a POST and not a GET request? It looks like the AJAX call is the problem since $_POST is empty.

Comment: can you do `print_r($_GET)` ? I find it strange that you get `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  I also suggest using Fiddler or something to inspect headers. I think you did a post, but with everything encoded as query url.

Comment: @Pam Instead of `$_POST` use `$_REQUEST` and see if it's empty too.

Comment: I'm not, its been working for the last 6 months, then I moved to a dedicated server, this happens

Comment: See if that is `$_GET` or `$_POST`

Comment: I hate that sentence 'it has been working'. It is not working[period] :)

Comment: Array
(
    [ppRemember] => 35iq0m8oi3ldr1f8603sifpv52
    [__utma] => 201771013.995365705.1339148067.1339148067.1339155188.2
    [__utmc] => 201771013
    [__utmz] => 201771013.1339148067.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
    [__utmb] => 201771013.9.10.1339155188
)

is what I get when I use $_REQUEST

Comment: If you know that reason is in server contact to its support.

Comment: @Pam, is it because you don't want us to see any code?

Comment: @Pam, please update it in the question. Can't see via comments...

Comment: $_GET also returns an empty array, ill copy some code now

Comment: @Pam You need to show us the serverside code, since this is where you think it's not working. Showing us your clientside code and updating with debug info doesn't help.

Comment: @Pam How is the content posted to your recieving part?

Comment: its all in the post, "
                $.post("order/calculate.php", {
                    current_tab_1: current_tab,
                    current_subtab_1: current_subtab,
                    delivery_options: delivery_options.val(),
                    p_copies: p_copies.val(),
                    p_paper: p_paper.val(),
" this bit @Repox

Comment: @Pam Are you by any chance using any mod_rewrite rules?

Comment: @Repo I don't know... where should I look to find out? Is that a config thing?

Comment: `json_encode` is a built in function as from 5.2.0. Might by interesting to do a `phpinfo()` on the shared hosting and check PHP version.

Comment: @WouterH ahhhh well that explains that one, the PHP  version that came with the server is php 5.1.6 and I'm currently trying to update it, but because I have a Plesk control panel and need to use this the damn thing has a software bug and I'm waiting for support to get back to me

Comment: still doesn't explain why post won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out why everything wasn't working. Tried updating my server from 5.1.6 to 5.3 using plesk control panel, which ended up breaking halfway through the installation. When I finally got it working again I reverted back to 5.1.6 and decided to do the update another time. I presume it messed up my php installation, because after I updated to 5.3 successfully, everything started working again.